# Matching standalone a1 values using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string, how can I match all the standalone a1 values (for replacing) using regEx:

```
a1 +a1 +a1:a10 + b1 + c1:d10 + a1:a1 +a1+ a1 + a1
```

I.e. a1:a10, b1, c1:d10, a1:a1 should NOT be matched. One should assume a scenario where the string is dynamic and can change, having different ranges.

Desired match output: a1,a1,a1,a1,a1. "Standalone" implies it does not have a " : " e.g. a1:a1 is not standalone. Matching +a1 or [space]a1 is not acceptable.

In my efforts the biggest problem is eliminating a1:a1 and a1:a10 because javascript does not support negative look behind.

Please note: some a1's are pre/postfixed by a space, some are not e.g. +a1+ this should still be matched. We should also assume other operators such as *a1+

You can see my incomplete attempt here: http://regexr.com/3ahpl. <- My example incorrectly matches the a1 in a1:a10 and a1:a1, otherwise it achieves what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are replacing all these `a1` with `foo`, you can use:

```
var input = 'a1 +a1 +a1:a10 + b1 + c1:d10 + a1:a1 +a1+ a1 + a1 pa1';    
var re = /(^|[^:]\b)a1\b(?!:)/g;    
var arr=[];

while (m = re.exec(input)) { arr.push(m[1]); }

console.log ( arr );
["a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK8kU4/7)

Comment: getting there.. but its still capturing + and spaces.. the goal is just to match a clean a1, not +a1 or [space]a1

Comment: +a1+ is standalone opposed to +a1:a1+ is not standalone. Like I said in the above comment: standalone implies it does not have a leading or trailing " : ". I also quite clearly said: a1:a10, b1, c1:d10, a1:a1 should NOT be matched. All other a1 must be matched. Only a1 must be matched.

Comment: Expected output is a1,a1,a1,a1,a1. Emphasis on don't match it if it has a " : ". Dude, standalone means NO " : ".

Comment: Well if non-presence of colon is the requirement then that requirement has already been met by the answer as `(?!:)` means no following `:` and `[^:]` means no preceding colon. Check the demo link again. Your expected output doesn't make any sense since there is no `b1`, `c1` etc in output

Comment: I don't want to match b1 or c1 I want to match a1. I think we've cleared up what standalone means.

Comment: Ok, have a look at this example: http://regexr.com/3ahq1 this is what I want to achieve EXCEPT I don't want the highlighted a1 in a1:a10 and a1:a1 is wrong.

Comment: wrong: a1 [+a1] +a1:a10 + b1 + c1:d10 + a1:a1 [+a1]+[ a1] +[ a1] please DO NOT incorporate + or [space] in the output.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. You probably don't understand it well that is why I gave you regex101 link. Matched `a1` is in matched group #1 and what you're seeing highlighted text is full match (which will be there due to absence of lookbehind). Read my comment above for regex101 link and look for matches in **MATCH INFORMATION**

Comment: sorry pal I don't think you get it :) please DO NOT incorporate + or [space] in output.

Comment: Looks like it is the case other way round. Rather than looking at the code and output you're just looking at highlighted text, that is not how programmers work.

Comment: One last time **output is what is in matched group #1 not in matched group #0** and look at **MATCH INFORMATION** section where there is no `+` or space before `a1`.

Comment: Ok your code makes sense. I am still confused by the output on RegEx Demo.. but I am starting to see your point now. lol apologies.

Comment: Yes highlighted text is for full match but `MATCH INFORMATION` is for the data that you want. Since there is no lookbehind in JS therefore we are utilizing matched group feature. Rest should be clear from the code above.

Comment: Well done -> I had no clue you could take this approach!

Comment: I found a serious bug in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a1s = input.replace(/\S+a1\S+/g, function(m) { 
   return m.replace(/\W/g,"") == "a1" ? "foo" : m; 
});
```

Here we are capturing  removing any pluses and then checking if it is `a1`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct regex to fish out the `a1` only is `(?:^|[^:])\b(a1)\b(?!:)`. Here is the explanation:

**In English** the issue solution description is: select any `a1` element that is a word and it is not preceded by or followed by the `:` (colon).

In pure **Regular Expression** language the solution would be:

```
(?<!:)\b(a1)\b(?!:)
```

where `a1` is surrounded by word boundary `\b(a1)\b` with a negative look-behind for a colon `(?<!:)`, and negative look-ahead for colon `(?!:)`.

However there is a problem with the **JavaScript** regex as it does not support negative look-behind syntax, so we have to [**mimic it**](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) somehow. Thus we need to replace the negative look-behind part with a non capturing group that states the preceding character can not be a colon `[^:]`. Expression seems to be fine with the exception for the first `a1` that starts at the input beginning. For that we have the symbol `^` that we stick to the allowed characters group `(?:^|[^:])`. After that all work like a charm.

Here is the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qK8kU4/6)

```js
var input = "a1 +a1 + ca1+ +a1:a10 + b1 + c1:d10 + a1:a1 +a1+ a1 + a1"
var regex = /(?:^|[^:])\b(a1)\b(?!:)/g
var arr = []
while (m = regex.exec(input)) arr.push(m[1]);
alert(arr)
```

BTW issue with the Anubhava's solution is that it does not check correctly the word `a1` boundary and could pick up a word like `ca1`